# Compound index with sort

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Below is my query/index. When I have it setup this way mongo will get spammed with recursive lock entries.

**Query:**

```
  this._db.findAndModify(
    {
      name: jobName,
      disabled: { $ne: true },
      nextRunAt: {$lte: this._nextScanAt},      
      $or: [
        {lockedAt: null},
        {lockedAt: {$exists: false}},
        {lockedAt: {$lte: lockDeadline}}
      ]      
    },
    {'priority': -1},
    {$set: {lockedAt: now}},
    {'new': true},
    findJobsResultWrapper(this, cb)
  );
```

**Index:**

```
  {name: 1, disabled: 1, nextRunAt: 1, lockedAt: 1}
```

.....
If I remove the **{'priority': -1}** and just replace it it **{}** then everything works perfectly. So I just can't seem to crack the code of a compound index with a sort field.

I have also tried:

```
{name: 1, disabled: 1, nextRunAt: 1, lockedAt: 1, priority: -1}
```

and

```
{priority: -1}
{name: 1, disabled: 1, nextRunAt: 1, lockedAt: 1}
```

No matter what I do if I put that sort in there then the DB grinds to a halt.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried doing an explain on the query? Also MongoDB isn't good with $ne in indices so try disabled:false instead.

Comment: Why the compound index anyway? You're using `.findAndModify()` which though it has a "sort" option to determine which document, it is only capable of modifying a single document at a time. Ergo, just use the primary key `_id`. You're other-thinking this.

Comment: I need to use the sort because the findAndModify may find multiple results but I need to sort on priority so the document with the highest priority is at the top of the results and that is the one that is ultimately modified by the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to eliminate any recursive locks when running the query by doing the following:

1. Have the priority as the first field in the query
2. Have the priority as the first field in the index

I tried moving the location of the priority field, I tried having the priority as its own index for the sort, but the find and modify wanted to use the same query for the find and for the sort and priority had to be in each so that they could use the same index.

**Query:**

```
 this._db.findAndModify(
    {
      priority: {$exists: true},            
      name: jobName,
      disabled: { $ne: true },
      nextRunAt: {$lte: this._nextScanAt},      
      $or: [
        {lockedAt: null},
        {lockedAt: {$exists: false}},
        {lockedAt: {$lte: lockDeadline}}
      ]
    },
    {priority: -1},
    {$set: {lockedAt: now}},
    {'new': true},
    findJobsResultWrapper(this, cb)
  );
```

**Index:**

```
{priority: -1, name: 1, disabled: 1, nextRunAt: 1, lockedAt: 1}
```